# Load/Read ressources JBOSS as 7

Tags: spring, jsf, deployment, resources

I recently working to migrate a jsf 1.2 project from Jboss 5 to JBoss 7.1.1 Final. everything worked like a charm when I deployed the application for the first time but it's not stable , as an example in 10 times,the app is deployed with success 8 and failed two times.

and the deployment failed only when the app is trying to load an external resources as  .xml conf or .proprieties that are injected in the classPath. I believe it's not an issue of access permissions to file system but I'm not sure why how I can resolve this issue, even when I'm trying to print the log error description here it tooks me to restart the server nine time to trace the issue

the first error when the app is trying to load an XML conf file and you found the log in the attached link error1-log ,it's the same case the second but I'm trying to read a .proprieties error2-log ,

I've scoured google for days and tried several different iterations configurations as define a separate module to load resources, change directory permissions,implement Jboss policy security.  I'm finally breaking down and asking for some help.

I'm definitely open to ideas , thanks.

error1-log :

```
00:44:47,387 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [br/com/murah/audixpress/core/config/context/applicationContext-DB.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [br/com/murah/audixpress/core/config/context/applicationContext-DB.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMappingResources#2cc29ba3' of type [br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMappingResources] while setting bean property 'mappingLocations';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMappingResources#2cc29ba3' defined in class path resource [br/com/murah/audixpress/core/config/context/applicationContext-DB.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static java.lang.String[] br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMappingResources.extrair()] threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.inicializacao.ContextLoaderAudi.loadParentContext(ContextLoaderAudi.java:26) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:195) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.inicializacao.InicializadorListener.contextInitialized(InicializadorListener.java:134) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

error2-log :

```
00:51:55,006 ERROR [br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMessage] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Erro no key: Idioma_Portugues, Resource: GERAL: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name br.com.murah.audixpress.core.messageResourcesTemp.MessageResources_geral, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:952) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationResourceBundle.getResourceBundle(ApplicationResourceBundle.java:124) [jsf-impl.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getResourceBundle(ApplicationAssociate.java:490) [jsf-impl.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getResourceBundle(ApplicationImpl.java:414) [jsf-impl.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMessage.getMessage(MurahMessage.java:512) [classes:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMessage.access$0(MurahMessage.java:500) [classes:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.utils.MurahMessage$Geral.getMessage(MurahMessage.java:419) [classes:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.core.utils.view.LocaleUtils.<clinit>(LocaleUtils.java:34) [classes:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.core.utils.view.LocaleExterno.getListaLocale(LocaleExterno.java:66) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72) [jsf-impl.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:121) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:337) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:307) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:524) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567) [jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar:1.1.15.B1]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100) [richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110) [jsf-impl.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100) [jsf-impl.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl.jar:1.2_12-b01-FCS]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266) [jsf-api-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.core.servlets.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:58) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.springSecurity.PrazoExpiracaoSenhaFilter.doFilter(PrazoExpiracaoSenhaFilter.java:48) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.view.MurahExceptionFilter.doFilter(MurahExceptionFilter.java:51) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.com.murah.audixpress.web.view.MurahControlFilter.doFilter(MurahControlFilter.java:100) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

Comment: Include stack trace in question itself (in code block), not in an external resource.

Comment: I believed that it will be more efficient to read, you found above the first log error :

Comment: @BalusC , I have included the log in the trace .